# Python RegEx Stop before a Word

Tags: python, regex

I have a bit of RegEx I am trying to figure out: `( of [A-Za-z ]+)?`

The above portion of my Regex will match the following:

> of New Mexico and Mrs Smith.

What I am trying to do is have the RegEx stop before `and`.

`( of [A-Za-z ]+)\sand?`

The above RegEx is very close to solving the issue however it still matches and.

The above matches:

> of New Mexico and

I want it to output:

> of New Mexico

Comment: What **exactly** are you trying to do by stopping before `and` ? I mean there should be some logical pattern here that regex could match.

Comment: do you mean with this specific text or in general? what are the expected inputs?

Comment: Is this what you want ? `of\s([A-Za-z ]+)\sand?`

Comment: I don't want and or anything after to be matched. The inputs vary and sometimes AND will not even be in the text. For example: Mark of New Mexico. "of New Mexico" will match. Mark of New Mexico and Tom of West Virginia. will also match. I want to stop the match before "and"

Comment: Please edit your post and put: A test case with an input phrase and the output you'd like to see

Comment: Dex'ter that is VERY close but still matches and

Comment: @Dex'ter: it will match `of New Mexico anything`. `and?` does not do what you are suggesting it does.

Comment: You could do it this way: `(.*)\sand`. [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nQ4gA3/2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
( of (?:(?!\band\b)[A-Za-z ])+)?
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gM5nM5/1)

The `(?:(?!\band\b)[A-Za-z ])+` construct matches 1+ characters defined in the `[A-Za-z ]` character class that are not  a whole word `and`.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/jjLpzx):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'( of (?:(?!\band\b)[A-Za-z ])+)?')
s = " of New Mexico and Mrs Smith."
m = p.search(s)
if m:
    print(m.group().strip())
```

Comment: You are welcome. Note that the tempered greedy token can be considered a multicharacter "synonym" for a negated character class. You cannot use `[^and]+` since it would just fail to match individual characters `a`, `n` and `d`. When using the tempered greedy token, you disallow matching the *sequence* of characters.